# Self Tracking Entities ListView Binding Losing Value On Change

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, entity-framework, mvvm

My application is using Self-Tracking Entities & I get my data from a WCF Service. In my WCF service query I am using the .Include("") to load entity relationships with my query.

```
    public List<IndividualDisability> GetIndividualDisabilities()
    {
        using (var context = new ADATrackingEntities())
        {
            return context.IndividualDisabilities.OfType<IndividualDisability>().Include("ADACode").ToList();
        }
    }
```

I'm then adding the results to an ICollectionView. I have a ListView that is bound to the ICollectionView, some of the columns in my ListView are bound to values from my entities relationship. I have a master-details setup with the current item of the listview bound to the entity object i'm editing.

```
<ListView Margin="0,0,10,0" MaxHeight="400" MaxWidth="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IndividualDisabilitiesSource}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentIndividualDisability, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemContainerStyle}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Case #" Width="Auto"  
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Individual.CaseNumberShort}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="LName" Width="Auto"  
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Individual.LastName}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="FName" Width="Auto"  
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Individual.FirstName}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="ADA Code" Width="Auto" 
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ADACode.ADACodeDesc}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The problem is that on my edit section i'm using a combobox to change a value from the selected record and its changing the related value in my ListView to a blank value in the cell. The only way I can get it to show up again is by going back to the database and loading the data again. Is there something im missing with my combobox or listview binding??

```
<ComboBox Height="25" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding ADACodesSource}"
    DisplayMemberPath="ADACodeDesc" SelectedValuePath="ADACodeID" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentIndividualDisability.ADACodeID, Mode=TwoWay, 
    NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

Comment: If you look in the Output console while this code is running, do you see any binding errors?

Comment: Looks like you are only setting a different id for the property you are trying to change. Are you handling changing the actual object (ADACode) in the property setter?
I would probably bind SelectedItem with 'ADACode' in stead of the SelectedValue/SelectedValuePath bound with 'ADACodeId.
Same DisplayMemberPath.

Comment: I'm not seeing any binding errors, but when I bind with SelectedItem instead it actually changes the value properly in the listview as expected. However, it is not setting the value in the combobox now. I do have TwoWay binding set as well. Any ideas?

Comment: I've posted a sample project that replicates the error over on the MSDN WPF forums. Hopefully that can help show my table relationships and my situation a little better. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0b174b74-4824-4edc-90dd-da381ec184d5

Comment: Anybody have any ideas?? I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with binding to an `ICollectionView`, which tracks the `CurrentItem` and often WPF controls that have an `ItemsSource` by default will bind to the `CurrentItem`. I'm a bit unclear about how your application is put together, but try adding `IsSyncrhonizedWithCurrentItem="False"` to your ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent been able to get it working still with the combobox, so I settled for creating a custom control. Its an AutoComplete/ComboBox that seems to have the correct type of binding. Everything works great with this control detailed in this blog post:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/07/06/creating-an-combobox-style-autocompletebox-control-in-silverlight.aspx

Comment: For anyone having this issue with the normal combobox control. I fixed it by setting IsSyncronizedWithCurrentItem=true in the combobox properties. All is working now.